# How can I get a count of unique parents grouped by child's last created date?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

A `parent` has many `children`, where each `child` has a `created_at` column.

Let's assume the data looks something like this:

```
Parent 1:  
- Child 1, created_at (last week sometime)
- Child 2, created_at (yesterday)
Parent 2:
- Child 3, created_at (today)
Parent 3:
- Child 4, created_at (today)
```

Using PostgreSQL through Rails, how can I get a count of unique `parents` grouped by `child`'s most recent `created_at`? The output should look something like this: `[Yesterday: 1, Today: 2]`. Note that the `created_at` from last week is not returned since the parent has a more recent child.

I'll take either raw SQL or ActiveRecord query form. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Max(Created_at), parentName from parentTable inner join ChildTable on child.FKey = ParentTable.PKey Group by parentName
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Assuming there is a time part in your `created_at` field, I am removing the time part before grouping. This will group the children by `created day`.

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', c.created_at), COUNT(c.id)
FROM Parent p
    JOIN Child c on p.id = c.parent_id
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', c.created_at)
ORDER BY date_trunc('day', c.created_at) DESC
```